# Show next file input after current file input has a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display the first list item and then when the first input file has a file selected i want to display the next list item and so on, I've been having issues with this. How should I approach this?

```
<li id="0"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="1"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="2"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="3"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="4"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="5"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="6"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="7"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="8"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>

<li id="9"><input size="30" name="images[]" class="my-input-file" type="file"></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all the input elements initially, and then attach event listeners to the input elements. If a file is specified, you would show the parent `li` element's next sibling.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmczm5cb/)

```
$('ul>li:not(:first)').hide();
$('ul>li>input').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value) {
        $(this).parent().next().show();
    }
});
```

---

If you want to determine whether one of the the previously shown elements changes and a file is unselected, you could use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxe9qp27/)

```
$('ul>li:not(:first)').hide();
$('ul>li>input').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value) {
        $(this).parent().next().show();
    }
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').prevAll().find('input').filter(function () {
        return !this.value;
    }).parent().nextAll().hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Worked perfect!